# Which Context to use in a activity class?

Tags: java, android, view, android-context

I have a class defined as

```
public class viewGroups extends ListActivity
```

Somewhere in the class I have

```
objItem = new clsContactGroups(context);
```

I am wondering what is advised to be used here? Which context?
I know four choices, but maybe there are others...

```
this
this.getApplicationContext()
this.getBaseContext()
this.getParent()
```

I use this Context to show a Toast. So I would like to show on the front-most view visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this`.  The toast will be associated with your ListActiviy, which is what you are looking for.  The ApplicationContext is not suitable (I'm not sure what would happen) and I think the getBaseContext() is probably going to return the same as the Application Context.  getParent() would be a good choice if your activity is embedded in another, but this should be rare.